# How can you write formulas in SE?

Tags: discussion, support

In this answer: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/61693/44505 I had difficulties writing the formulas, but thankfully SE - stop firing the good guys fixed it. How can I write formulas in SE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has already been [posted on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76902/154443) but the best post, unsurprisingly, has been posted on [Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) - I don't think it is worthwhile posting an answer with all that content here, so my advice to you is just to follow the guidance in that link.